# nothing to compile in hardhat(yarn)

Tags: hardhat, nodejs

I have created a project in VS Code and I'm using Hardhat with Yarn for it. However, when I run the compile command `yarn hardhat compile`, I encounter an issue where I receive a "nothing to compile" error. I'm confident that I followed the steps correctly as demonstrated in a YouTube video, but unfortunately, my project is not compiling. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile your contracts once and then try compiling them again without making any changes to the source code, then you will see `nothing to compile`.

To see that your compiled contracts, you can have a look at the `artificats` directory that is generated during compilation.

If you want to do a fresh compilation, then do `yarn hardhat clean`, this deletes the compiled contracts. Then you can try compiling again.

Comment: Actually, I noticed that there isn't an "artifacts" folder generated; only a "cache" folder is created. I attempted to perform a fresh compilation, but the issue persists.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to generate the "artifacts" folder when I attempt to compile.

Comment: The solution to my problem was related to the folder name. Instead of naming the folder "contracts" (plural), I mistakenly named it "contract" (singular), which was causing the issue.